# Cannot set Magento2 to Production Mode

Tags: magento2, deploy, production-mode, ssh

I tried to put my website into Production mode.

For this, I used the following command on SSH but it get stuck.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Please refer to the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: try deploying the static content separately after compilation if it stuckes in the same process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following command to skip compilation, so you can directly set production mode without any compilation or static content deploy.

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

Comment: we should have compiled code in production, skipping it is not recommended.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if you want to set on production mode then first set to production mode, we can run compilation anytime after that, some time some its not working because of third party extension.

Comment: so we can use --skip-compilation temperory

Comment: @AasimGoriya Hi, how can i compile the code after production mode?

Comment: @KevinLee you can run this command for compilation. : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`